# Ordenar líneas de un texbox multiline en c# de menor a mayor

Tags: c#

Buenas tengo un pequeño inconveniente estoy realizando un programa en c# y quiero que un botón me ordene las líneas ingresadas en un texbox multiline  de menor a mayor el el texbox tengo la siguiente info

> 2 plástico
>   1 metal
>   5 cobre
>   3 aluminio

La idea esq me lo presente así pero en el mismo texbox

> 1 metal
>   2 plástico
>   3 aluminio
>   5 cobre

Agradezco de antemano todas sus ayudas

Comment: ¿Qué has hecho hasta ahora?

Comment: Bienvenido a [so]. Necesitaríamos que mostraras en tu pregunta que tienes hasta ahora y que problemas te has encontrado. Te invito a te pases por el [tour] y leas la página de ayuda [ask]. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Podrias procesar las lineas separando cada datos, lo primero es generar la estructura de datos

```
public class Item{
   public int Nro {get;set;}
   public string Descripcion {get;set;}
}
```

Luego se procesan las lineas usando el `spit()`

```
List<Item> listItems = new List<Item>();

string lineas[] lineas = TextBox1.Lines;

forach(string linea in lineas)
{
   string[] partes = linea.Split(' ');
   Item item = new Item() { 
         Nro = Convert.ToInt32(partes[0]), 
         Descripcion = partes[1])
   };

   listItems.Add(item);
}
```

por ultimo puedes ordenar y mostrar el resultado

```
var listItemsSorted = listItems.OrderBy(x=> x.Nro);

TextBox1.Clear();

List<string> orderLines = new List<string>();
foreach(var item in listItemsSorted)
{
  orderLines.Add(string.Format("{0} {1}", item.Nro, item.Descripcion));
}

TextBox1.Lines = orderLines.ToArray();
```

Asi despues de procesar las lineas puede volver a mostrarlas ordenadas con la ayuda de `linq`

Answer (score 0):

Para ordenar, necesitas separar el contenido en líneas:

```
var lineas = texbox.Text.Split('\n');
```

Una vez separado, puedes ordenarlo:

```
var lineas_ordenadas = texbox.Text.Split('\n').OrderBy(s => s);
```

Puedes sobrescribir el texto del cuadro de texto una vez ordenado:

```
texbox.Text = String.Join("\n", texbox.Text.Split('\n').OrderBy(s => s));
```